# Can I confirm that someone payed me only by transaction ID?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

I'm trying to sell something through monero,  but I wanna know that he has really payed me.  How can I do that?

Say my associate payed me already and the monero came through succesfully, how could I make sure it was him who payed me? Should I ask first for a transaction ID,  and then confirm it by running "show_transfers" command on "monero-wallet-cli"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. (Most common) You could give out a unique payment ID to the buyer. This is easily done using an integrated address, which automatically instructs the buyer's wallet to use that particular payment ID. You'd then wait for an incoming payment that specifies that payment ID. This is easiest for a seller, because they don't have to chase the buyer later to ask for additional information.
2. You could ask the buyer to use a random payment ID and tell you what it was.
3. You could ask the buyer to tell you the transaction ID after they've made payment.